# Add data to XML file with Filemaker Pro

Tags: xml, filemaker

I got a filemaker pro application where I export some posts from the DB as XML. I got a xls file and Filemaker creates ok xml files. Im using the built in "Export posts" But how can I add data-posts to a xml file?

Lets consider i got an xml file like this that my application exported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people xml:lang="en-us">
    <person>
        <name>Adam</name>
        <age>46</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Benard</name>
        <age>37</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

But at a later point in time I want to add a post for Carol, age 31 so my xml file become

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people xml:lang="en-us">
    <person>
        <name>Adam</name>
        <age>46</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Benard</name>
        <age>37</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Carol</name>
        <age>31</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

Can I do this easy in filemaker pro?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do this easy in filemaker pro?

Technically, it is possible - but it certainly won't be easy.

What you can do is to modify your XSLT stylesheet so that it incorporates the previously exported XML into the output XML. Then overwrite the previously exported XML file with the one you have exported just now.

There is probably a better way to accomplish your *real* goal, but we don't know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

> using the built in "Export posts"

The built in FileMaker functionality you are using is Export XML. "Export posts" is the name of the script which exports XML.

It is an export. You can export one record or one thousand - the Export is going to be the same, no need to change your Export mapping or xsl file.

On the other hand, you might want to check how FileMaker collects the data for export, most probably some search or the export function works on the current found set.